# How to make the unit test execute a particular test case everytime when it sees a certain function in the executing java project?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am having a build failure issue while running a bunch of unit test over a java project. I am getting the **NoClassDefFoundError** which is happening because of the lack of ability for the *unit test to get the dependencies*. I am trying to *mock an object* for the class and then call the function, but the code is structured in a way that is getting a bit complex for me to handle the issue. I am very new to unit testing. I have provided below, a sample of code structure that my project has

```
Class ServiceProvider(){

   obj declarations;

   public void mainFunction(){

       //Does a couple of things and calls a function in another class
       boolean val = subFunction();
  }           

  public boolean subFunction(){ 
       boolean val = AnotherClass.someFunction(text); 
       //this function throws lots of exceptions and all those are caught and handled 
       return val;
  }


@RunsWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
Class UnitTestBunch(){

@Mock
AnotherClass acObj = new AnotherClass();

@InjectMock
ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider();

@Test
public void unitTest1() throws Exception{

   when(acObj.someFunction(text)).thenReturn(true);

}

@Test
public void unitTest2() throws Exception{

    thrown.expect(ExceptionName.Class);
    sp.mainFunction();
}
```

I have a test that uses the mock object and performs the function call associated with that class. But, the issue here is that there are a bunch of other unit test cases that are written similar to the unitTest2 function and *calls the mainFunction at the end of the test*. This mainFunction invokes someFunction() and causes NoCalssDefFoundError(). I am trying to make the unit test execute the content in unitTest1 everytime when it sees the AnotherClass.someFunction().  I am not sure if this is achievable or not. There could be another better way to resolve this issue. Could someone please pitch in some ideas?

Comment: why are you doing unit testing when you have build failures? when Build error occurs, No Class Def Found means you cannot even mock the object because the object does not even exist. I am guessing you are using web service and trying to auto generate the class using build. When build fail, the class will NOT get generated. thus you get this error. It is like calling "SomeRandomClassObject" that never existed at first place.

Comment: The build is not supposed to fail. The inclusion of a new function in the java project is causing the build failure with the unit testing. Trying to manage the unit test cases to avoid the build failure

Comment: Unit test is independent with the build unless whoever in your team decided to put some logic into the test and tries to generate the class pojo from the test class (which is bad, since junit only does the testing and never the logic.) If that is not the case then I think it failure might due to your build configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you seem to be using `unitTest1` for *setup*, not for testing anything. When you run a unit test, each test should be able to run separately or together, in any order.

You're using JUnit4 in your tests, so it would be very easy to add the statement you have in `unitTest1` into a `@Before` method. JUnit4 will call this method before each test method (annotated with `@Test`).

```
@Before
public void stubAcObj() throws Exception{
  when(acObj.someFunction(text)).thenReturn(true);
}
```

The method may be named anything, though `setUp()` is a common name borrowed from a method to override in JUnit3. However, it must be annotated with `org.junit.Before`.

If you need this from multiple test cases, you should just create a helper, as you would with any code. This doesn't work as well with `@InjectMocks`, but you may want to avoid using `@InjectMocks` in general as it will fail silently if you add a dependency to your system-under-test.

```
public class AnotherClassTestHelper {
  /** Returns a Mockito mock of AnotherClass with a stub for someFunction. */
  public static AnotherClass createAnotherClassMock() {
    AnotherClass mockAnotherClass = Mockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);
    when(mockAnotherClass.someFunction(text)).thenReturn(true);
    return mockAnotherClass;
  }
}
```

---

As a side note, this is a counterintuitive pattern:

```
/* BAD */
@Mock
AnotherClass acObj = new AnotherClass();
```

You create a new, real AnotherClass, then instruct Mockito to overwrite it with a mock (in MockitoJUnitRunner). It's much better just to say:

```
/* GOOD */
@Mock AnotherClass acObj;
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about the helper class and the code you have provided for that?

Comment: There's nothing special about it: It behaves exactly the same as any other library function you would write, and its return value is a new mock for AnotherClass with all the stubbing you need. If you always need AnotherClass stubbed the same way, this might be an advantage over copying and pasting the `someFunction` set-up many times.

Comment: I modified the **@Test** to **@Before** for unitTest1() and altered the object declaration as per your suggestion. I am still getting build failure with same exceptions, but pointing to a different subFunction() this time.